# putting a file of defines into an array

Tags: php, file

having a file with the following for example:

```
DEFINE('INTERESTS_1','a');
DEFINE('INTERESTS_2','d');
DEFINE('INTERESTS_3','g');
DEFINE('INTERESTS_4','c');
```

Is it possible to open it, put it into an array and then ordering it ASC beforing echoing it all out using a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// capture constant before loading the new ones
$before = get_defined_constants();

// require_file
// require_once 'somefile';

DEFINE('INTERESTS_1','a'); // this is for testing
DEFINE('INTERESTS_2','d'); // "
DEFINE('INTERESTS_3','g'); // "
DEFINE('INTERESTS_4','c'); // "

$new = array_diff(get_defined_constants(), $before);

// sort, or do whatever you want with those values
asort($new);

// debug output
foreach ($new as $constantName => $constantValue) {
  echo $constantName, ' ', $constantValue, "\n";
}
```

Comment: how can I then put the values into a loop and echo them out into a table?? thanks

Comment: @JakeStainer I changed the example, have a look at the `foreach` at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, use [get_defined_constants()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-constants.php) and then use [sort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) to sort the array of constants and of course, use a foreach loop to echo out what you want.

Comment: so within get_defined:constants can i specify that they must start with INTERESTS ?

Comment: PHP has predefined constants and then there are the constants that you define. If you pass in `true` into get_defined_constants(), PHP will categorize them into predefined and user defined. If you don't, they will be mixed together.

However, Yoshi's example is a lot better. I neglected to consider the fact that you wanted constants defined in a single file. My method will return all constants defined everywhere in the script, by you.

Answer (score 0):

Yeap... Use $GLOBALS to print them, and natsort them http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php